# If I replicate a UX strategy from a popular app for my app, is there any proof that it'll work for my users?

Tags: user-behavior, user-research, user-centered-design, social-interfaces

Let's say for e.g I replicate the Facebook app but as another social media platform. My users are similar to facebook's users, their habits and lifestyle are similar too, would that guarantee me success in terms of UX alone?.

Let's keep aside the fact that it is a blatant copy and concentrate on user getting habituated to a certain behaviour, if I replicate that would this warrant my success?
Are there any case studies or reports I could look at that would answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good UX ensures that things work in specific contexts for specific users. Things that work on one site for one set of users come with no broad guarantees. See *[Should You Copy a Famous Site's Design?](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/copying-a-famous-sites-design/)*  by Jakob Nielson.

Comment: That was a great read. Essentially it boiled down to the fact that big websites aren't perfect, they can afford to make mistakes and their designers are constantly learning. How about user habituation, how do these companies habituate users to a certain information architecture?

Comment: That blurb about the user filling out the sign _up_ form but clicking the sign _in_ button for **20 minutes** really embodies the type of user we struggle to accommodate.